# Problems using enctype="multipart/form-data" with $_POST variables

Tags: php, html, forms, post, encoding

When setting the `enctype` to `multipart/form-data` in an HTML form, `$_POST` variables will not be set.  The variables are set without the enctype but it must be in order to use the $_FILES array.  Is there an alternative to using the `$_FILES` array?

Bug report: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=26004

The bug *can be* fixed by updating Apache, however I would like to find a possible workaround before I resort to doing that.

**EDIT: After updating to the latest version of Apache, the problem still persists.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you set the enctype to `multipart/form-data`, `$_POST` will be populated.

You are able to access the data via [`php://input`](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php) or `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` alternatively, in case the enctype is not `multipart/form-data` which might be an alternative for you to access the data.

Comment: Doesn't $_FILES only recieve $_POST data?

Comment: @hakre That is not true. You can use $_POST even if the enctype is `multipart/form-data`.

Comment: @xdazz Like I said, there is a bug.

Comment: @hakre The demo doesn't work for me. After submitting the file I get: http://cl.ly/AxTl

Comment: Which is correct. What are you missing? The `$_FILES` array? If so, add it to the var_dump.

Comment: @WillCoughlin What is your problem? You get your $_POST set, don't you?

Comment: @hakre Thank you, I forgot about the var_dump() function.

Answer (score 0):

Is possible that `file_uploads` may be disabled, check that it is enabled on your `php.ini`

```
file_uploads = On
```

Comment: Also will need `upload_max_filesize`, `post_max_size`, `upload_tmp_dir` config values.